# iOS 6 Maps crash occasionally on iPad3 mainly when I rotate

Tags: ios6-maps

I'm getting my application crashed when I rotate my iPad here below the detailed scenario 
I have a  map screen where I display a map with couple of 'pins'/'annotations'  , the screen works almost all the time perfectly but sometimes  it crashes mainly when I rotate the map screen .

I have tried to check out the different logs : 
At run time and after the crash the application was stopped  at the below line  :

```
IMGSGX543GLDriver`sgxTextureGetImageRowBytes(GLDTextureRec*, unsigned int, unsigned int):
```

From the device console :

```
Feb  9 13:13:23 iPad3 awdd[4970] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Feb  9 13:13:23 iPad3 awdd[4970] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
Feb  9 13:13:24 iPad3 awdd[4970] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyCTInfoWithBlock: _CTServerConnectionCopyFirmwareVersion: CommCenter error: 1:45 (Operation not supported)
Feb  9 13:13:24 iPad3 awdd[4970] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyCTInfoWithBlock: _CTServerConnectionCopyFirmwareVersion: CommCenter error: 1:45 (Operation not supported)
Feb  9 13:13:24 iPad3 awdd[4970] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyCTInfoWithBlock: _CTServerConnectionCopyFirmwareVersion: CommCenter error: 1:45 (Operation not supported)
Feb  9 13:13:24 iPad3 awdd[4970] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyCTInfoWithBlock: _CTServerConnectionCopyFirmwareVersion: CommCenter error: 1:45 (Operation not supported)
```

BR,

Comment: I am experiencing a similar intermittent crash and would love an answer as well. My crash involves the map view loading as a blank black area and then crashing the app. This suggests to me a failure of the map to load properly, but since it is intermittent it is hard to trace the cause.

Comment: in fact in my viewDidLoad I added the below control and seems it worked for me :  if(self.mapView.annotations){
     [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
    }

Comment: I'm seeing this as well and only on iOS 6.0 (any iPad model that supports 6.0).  I'll try the annotation fix, thanks!